# ParentDataWidget Error, I want the focused number of WheelScroll to get assigned to a variable

Tags: flutter

`ParentDataWidget` Error, I want the focused number of WheelScroll to get assigned to a variable, here is my code:

main.dart

```
import 'input_page.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

void main() => runApp(BMICalculator());

class BMICalculator extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<BMICalculator> createState() => _BMICalculatorState();
}

class _BMICalculatorState extends State<BMICalculator> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(colorScheme: ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
        primary: Color(0xfffafafa),
        background: Color(0xfffafafa),
      ),
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText2: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xFF57616B),
              fontFamily: "Helvetica"
          ),
        ),
      ),

      home: Expanded(child: InputPage()),
    );
  }
}
```

input_page.dart

```
import 'package:bmi_calculator/ft.dart';
import 'package:bmi_calculator/inch.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide BoxDecoration, BoxShadow;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inset_box_shadow/flutter_inset_box_shadow.dart';
import 'ftTxt.dart';
import 'classes.dart';


class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    int finalFt = 0;
    int finalInch = 0;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('BMI Calculator',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24,
            fontFamily: "Helvetica",
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: Color(0xFF57616B),
          ),),
      ),
      body:
      SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Him(ht: 120,marginLeft: 25,marginRight: 15,
                      cardChild: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,5,0,0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: ClipRect(child: Align(alignment:Alignment.topCenter, child: Image.asset('assets/male.png',),heightFactor: 0.49,),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                  ),
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      if(himPressed = true){
                        herPressed = false;
                      }
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child:Her(ht: 120,marginRight: 25,marginLeft: 15,
                    cardChild: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3, 14,0,0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: ClipRect(child: Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                              child: Image.asset('assets/female.png'),heightFactor: 0.62,),),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onTap: (){
                    setState(() {
                      herPressed = !herPressed;
                      setState(() {
                        if(herPressed = true){
                          himPressed = false;
                        }
                      });
                      print(herPressed);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
            ),
            ReusableCard(ht: 210,marginLeft: 25,marginRight: 25,
                cardChild:Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,10,0,0),
                      child: Text('Height (inch)',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: "Helvetica",
                          fontSize:   16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),),
                    ),
                    Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(flex: 2,
                            child: ReusableCardsecond(ht: 120, marginLeft: 25, marginRight: 15,
                              cardChild:Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    color:Color(0xfff7faff),
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 2,
                                          child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                                              onSelectedItemChanged: (value){
                                                setState(() {
                                                  finalFt = value;
                                                });
                                              },
                                              itemExtent: 30,
                                              perspective: 0.00001,
                                              physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                                              childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                                                  childCount: 10,
                                                  builder: (context,index){
                                                    return Expanded(child: Feet(ft: index+1));
                                                  }
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(itemExtent: 50, childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                                              childCount: 1,
                                              builder: (context,index){
                                                return Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,6,2,4),
                                                  child: ftTxt(ftText: 'ft'),
                                                );
                                              }
                                          )),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(flex: 2,
                            child: ReusableCardsecond(ht: 120, marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 25,
                              cardChild: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    color:Color(0xfff7faff),
                                  ),
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Expanded(
                                          flex: 2,
                                          child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                                              onSelectedItemChanged: (value){
                                                setState(() {
                                                  finalInch = value;
                                                  print(finalInch);
                                                });
                                              },
                                              itemExtent: 30,
                                              perspective: 0.00001,
                                              physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                                              childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                                                  childCount: 12,
                                                  builder: (context,index){
                                                    return Expanded(child: Inch(inch: index+1));
                                                  }
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        Expanded(
                                          child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(itemExtent: 50, childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                                              childCount: 1,
                                              builder: (context,index){
                                                return Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,8,11,4),
                                                  child: Text('inch',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 17,
                                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                        color: Color(0xff666f78),
                                                        fontFamily: "Helvetica"
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                );
                                              }
                                          )),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ]
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
                      child: Text('$finalFt feet and $finalInch inches',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),),
                    ),
                  ],

                )
            ),
            Row( children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: ReusableCard(ht: 160,marginLeft: 25,marginRight: 15,
                  cardChild: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,20,0,0),
                        child: Text('Weight (kgs)',style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(33,30,33,20),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff5582f9),width: 3),),
                                hintText: '',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17,
                                )
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: ReusableCard(ht: 160,marginLeft: 15,marginRight: 25,
                  cardChild: Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,20,0,0),
                        child: Text('Age',style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 2,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(33,30,33,20),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30,
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xff5582f9),width: 3,)),
                                hintText: '',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 17,
                                )
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),),
              )
            ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            TextButton(
              child: Container(
                height: 70,
                width: double.maxFinite,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Calculate BMI',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xfffdfdfd),
                      fontFamily: "Helvetica",
                      fontSize: 17,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 0, 25, 0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                      spreadRadius: 3,
                      blurRadius: 15,
                      offset: Offset(0,0),
                    ),
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade100,
                      offset: Offset(0,0),
                      blurRadius: 15,
                      spreadRadius: 3,
                    )
                  ],
                  color: Color(0xff4e7df9),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: (){
                print('Button got pressed');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

classes.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_inset_box_shadow/flutter_inset_box_shadow.dart';


bool himPressed = false;
bool herPressed = false;
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard({required this.ht,required this.marginLeft, required this.marginRight,required this.cardChild});
  double ht;
  double marginLeft;
  double marginRight;
  Widget cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: cardChild,
      height: ht,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(marginLeft, 15, marginRight, 15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 15,
            offset: Offset(8,0),
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.shade100,
            offset: Offset(-9,0),
            blurRadius: 15,
            spreadRadius: 3,
          )
        ],
        color: Color(0xfffdfdfd),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Him extends StatefulWidget {
  Him({required this.ht,required this.marginLeft, required this.marginRight,required this.cardChild});

  double ht;
  double marginLeft;
  double marginRight;
  Widget cardChild;

  @override
  State<Him> createState() => _HimState();
}

class _HimState extends State<Him> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double blur = himPressed ? 3 : 15;
    Offset distance = himPressed ? Offset(0,0): Offset(8, 0);

    return GestureDetector(
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        child: widget.cardChild,
        height: widget.ht,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(widget.marginLeft, 15,widget.marginRight, 15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: himPressed ? Color(0xff4e7df9) : Colors.grey.shade200,width: 2),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
              spreadRadius: 1,
              blurRadius: blur,
              offset: distance,
              inset: himPressed,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.shade100,
              offset: -distance,
              blurRadius: blur,
              spreadRadius: 3,
              inset: himPressed,
            )
          ],
          color: Color(0xfffdfdfd),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
    );

  }
}


class Her extends StatefulWidget {
  Her({required this.ht,required this.marginLeft, required this.marginRight,required this.cardChild});

  double ht;
  double marginLeft;
  double marginRight;
  Widget cardChild;

  @override
  State<Her> createState() => _HerState();
}

class _HerState extends State<Her> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double blur = herPressed ? 5 : 15;
    Offset distance = herPressed ? Offset(0,0): Offset(8, 0);

    return GestureDetector(
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        child: widget.cardChild,
        height: widget.ht,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(widget.marginLeft, 15,widget.marginRight, 15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: herPressed ? Color(0xff4e7df9) : Colors.grey.shade200,width: 2),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.shade300,
              spreadRadius: 1,
              blurRadius: blur,
              offset: distance,
              inset: herPressed,
            ),
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.shade100,
              offset: -distance,
              blurRadius: blur,
              spreadRadius: 3,
              inset: herPressed,
            )
          ],
          color: Color(0xfffdfdfd),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),

    );

  }
}
//      child: AnimatedContainer(
//   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
//         child: widget.cardChild,
//       height: widget.ht,
//       margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(widget.marginLeft, 15, widget.marginRight, 15),
//       decoration: BoxDecoration(
//         border: Border.all(color: isPressed ? Color(0xff4e7df9) : Colors.grey.shade200,width: 2),
//       boxShadow: [
//       BoxShadow(
//       color: Colors.grey.shade300,
//       spreadRadius: 1,
//       blurRadius: blur,
//       offset: distance,
//         inset: isPressed,
//       ),
//       BoxShadow(
//       color: Colors.grey.shade100,
//       offset: -distance,
//       blurRadius: blur,
//       spreadRadius: 3,
//         inset: isPressed,
//       )
//       ],
//       color: Color(0xfffdfdfd),
//       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
//       ),
//       ),


class ReusableCardsecond extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCardsecond({required this.ht,required this.marginLeft, required this.marginRight,required this.cardChild});

  double ht;
  double marginLeft;
  double marginRight;
  Widget cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: cardChild,
      height: ht,
      width: 140,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(marginLeft, 15, marginRight, 15),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
            spreadRadius: 1,
            blurRadius: 25,
            offset: Offset(0,0),
          ),
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey.shade100,
            offset: Offset(-1,0),
            blurRadius: 25,
            spreadRadius: 1,
          )
        ],
        color: Color(0xfffdfdfd),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

inch.dart

```
class Inch extends StatefulWidget {
  Inch({required this.inch});
  int inch;

  @override
  State<Inch> createState() => _InchState();
}

class _InchState extends State<Inch> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40,0,0,4),
        child: Text( widget.inch.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 17,
              fontFamily: "Helvetica"
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ft.dart

```
class Feet extends StatefulWidget {
  Feet({required this.ft});
  int ft;

  @override
  State<Feet> createState() => _FeetState();
}

class _FeetState extends State<Feet> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40,0,0,4),
        child: Text( widget.ft.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 17,
              fontFamily: "Helvetica"
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ftTxt.dart

```
class ftTxt extends StatelessWidget {
  ftTxt({required this.ftText});
  var ftText;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,5,15,4),
      child: Container(
        child: Text(ftText,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 17,
              color: Color(0xff666f78),
              fontFamily: "Helvetica"
          ),
        ),
        color: Color(0xfff7faff),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot Of the error]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This usage is wrong.
The widget you send to the home parameter will already occupy the entire screen.
You don't need to use Expanded,Flexible for this.

These expansion widgets can only be used below widgets that have space to expand.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.dart`, remove the `Expanded` widget. You only allowed to use it directly inside `Row` or `Column` widget, now you are using it wrong. So your home should be like this:

```
home: InputPage(),
```